# If the joint distribution of two r.v.'s are symmetric, $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq y, Y \leq x)$, why are their marginal distributions the same?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that two random variables $X,Y$ are symmetric, in that:

$$
P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq y, Y \leq x)
$$

I read that if this is satisfied, then the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are the same. Can anyone see why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: Take the limit $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: Why is it that $\lim_{x \to \infty}P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(Y \leq y)$? Is there a standard result in probability for this?

Comment: Because it is $\mathsf P(X\in \Bbb R, Y\in (-\infty;y])$, the probability that $Y$ is at most $y$ and $X$ is any real number.  @user321627

Answer (score 3):

Your supposition can also be written 
$$ P \left( X=x, Y=y \right) =  P \left( X=y, Y=x \right). $$ 
The marginal distribution is 
$$ P \left( X=x\right) = \sum_{y} P \left( X=x, Y=y \right) = \sum_{y} P \left( X=y, Y=x \right) =  P \left( Y =x\right)$$ 
i.e. the marginal distributions are the same.