# $F(x, y) = F(y, x)$ for two random variables

Tags: probability

This is Q6.1 of Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability:

> F(x, y) is the joint density function of random variables X and Y. If F(x, y) = F(y, x) what can you say about the distributions of the two random variables?

One answer that sounded "obvious" is that the two random variables are independent, but is that really it? Assuming that F(x, y) is the joint CDF of the two variables, I tried to write it as a double integral in terms of the PDF, but couldn't get any further insights from it (they mention "distributions" which I find confusing - don't think X and Y would be of a particular distribution, would it?)

I *think* I'm missing something, and would appreciate assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "Assuming that F(x, y) is the joint CDF", but the cited quote says it's the joint density function.

Comment: How is independence obvious? The converse is true, for sure, that when X, Y are independent then F(x, y) = F(y, x).

Comment: @r.e.s. I'm not sure - I made this assumption because Sheldon's book normally uses $f(x, y)$ (rather than $F(x, y)$) as the joint PDF.

Comment: @insipidintegrator In other words, when I first approached this question, I was like "well, if X and Y are independent this must be true" - but was not sure if I could use it the way I said above.

Comment: @Leaderboard If you compute the marginal distributions, the fact that $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ should allow you to say something about the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, no? After all $f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)dy =  \int_{\mathbb R} f(y,x)dy = f_Y(x)$.

Comment: The fact that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent does not seem to imply that $f_{X,Y}$ is symmetric unless $f_X = f_Y$, however...

Comment: @Pedro So $X = Y$?

Comment: No. But they have the same distribution.

Comment: @insipidintegrator no, being X and Y independent does not imply that $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$.

Comment: @nicola but independence implies $F_{X,Y}(x, y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y)$, so why not?

Comment: @insipidintegrator if X, Y are independent and identically distributed, then yes.just independent is not enough

Comment: @Ant but why? is there an order difference, like $F(x, y) =F_{X, Y}(x, y)$ and  $F(y, x) =F_{Y, X}(y, x)$? Or is there not?

Comment: $Ce^{-x + \alpha xy - y}$ on $[0, 1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator The point they're making is that if say $f(x,y) = Ce^{-x^2}e^{-2y^2}$ for $x,y\in (-\infty,\infty)$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but $f(x,y)\ne f(y,x).$ So independence doesn't necessarily suffice, unless the two variables have the same marginal distributions.

Comment: okay, I now see where I misunderstood what was meant.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146942/if-the-joint-distribution-of-two-r-v-s-are-symmetric-px-leq-x-y-leq-y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to come up with a complete answer all at once, or to just use some vague sense of intuition, it is instructive to consider specific examples of joint densities that satisfy the given conditions, and investigate their properties.  To this end, we will construct and discuss a few of these and leave a formal proof to the reader as an exercise.  For the purposes of this discussion, we will refer to the joint density as $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)$ when the context is understood.  We will also assume that the meaning of the given criterion is that $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X,Y}(y,x) \tag{$\star$}$$ for all $x,y$ in the joint support.

---

**Example 1.**

$$f(x,y) = e^{-x} e^{-y} , \quad x > 0, \quad y > 0. \tag{1}$$

It's easy to see that $(1)$ satisfies the given criterion; moreover, we may write $f$ in the form $f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ where $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$, and $x > 0$.  That is to say, $X$ and $Y$ are IID in this case.

**Example 2.**
$$f(x,y) = \frac{4}{3}(1-xy), \quad x, y \in [0,1]. \tag{2}$$

Again, we see that $(2)$ satisfies the given criterion.  It is also not difficult to see that we *cannot* represent $(2)$ as the product of two marginal densities.  Indeed, $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y] = -\frac{1}{81}$ which, if $X$ and $Y$ were independent, would instead be $0$.  Are $X$ and $Y$ identically distributed?  Yes.  The marginal density in each case is
$$f_X(x) = \frac{2}{3}(2-x), \quad 0 < x < 1, \\ f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{3}(2-y), \quad 0 < y < 1.$$

**Example 3.**

From the previous example we can see how to easily construct many such joint densities that obey the property $(\star)$; e.g.,
$$f(x,y) = \frac{2}{\pi^2} \cos^2 (x-y), \quad x, y \in [0,\pi]. \tag{3}$$
We simply need to choose a nonnegative function that is symmetric about $y = x$ but cannot be factored into the form $f(x)f(y)$.  Then we integrate over some domain and scale the function so that its integral over that domain is $1$.

Comment: (+1) Can also just vary the support to make them not independent while maintaining symmetry, e.g. let $(x,y)$ be uniformly distributed on the unit disk.